# Slick Slider Items arent visible when first loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm still extremely new to all of this so I am sorry if this question is stupid.

The slider is supposed to display a list item with an image and a caption. When the page is first loaded, there is just a giant empty space, only after I click on that space it is somewhat doing what it's supposed to do.

this is my code:

```css
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.preview:hover,
.arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.dropdownBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dropdownBtn:hover {
  background-color: #37264a;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
}

.dropdownBox:hover .dropdownContent {
  display: block;
}

.dropdownElement {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownElement>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.dropdownElement>a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownBox">
  <a class="dropdownBtn" href="#">Season 1</a>
  <ul class="dropdownContent">
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 1 Rose</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 2 The End of the World</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 3 The Unquiet Dead</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 4 Aliens of London</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried turning my list into multiple div elements but that didnt change anything and removing the classes from the list elements ended up scattering it all like crazy.

Where is the flaw in my CSS?
Would be incredibly grateful if someone found it!

[here's what the page looks like when it's first loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK6zl.jpg)
[and this is what it looks like after I click on the empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LlB7.jpg)

UPDATE I removed the 'preview' class and now it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDwtn.jpg)

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: no errors at all, it seems to me like there is a conflict with the css, I just cant figure out what exactly is causing it

Answer (score 2):

My colleague found a solution to this problem:

The `seasons` div as well as the `dropdownContent` were on `display:hidden` when the page first loaded, so Slick set the width of the slider to 0px and aligned all the slides outside the 0px box.

I changed `display:hidden` to `height:0px, overflow-y:hidden`instead, so now the slick slider loads as it should :)

Also, I added `.slick-prev { left: -5px;} .slick-next { right: -5px;}` to my stylesheet, since the arrows were causing a bit of trouble with the width of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.dropdownBtn` have no `background-color`, it will be white.

```css
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.preview:hover,
.arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.dropdownBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dropdownBtn:hover {
  background-color: #37264a;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
}

.dropdownBox:hover .dropdownContent {
  display: block;
}

.dropdownElement {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownElement>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.dropdownElement>a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownBox">
  <a class="dropdownBtn" href="#">Season 1</a>
  <ul class="dropdownContent">
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 1 Rose</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 2 The End of the World</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 3 The Unquiet Dead</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownElement  preview"> <img src="bilder/thumbnail-placeholder.jpg"><a href="#"> 4 Aliens of London</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The background is a dark image, so the font is visible.
My problem is that the content of my dropdown (that is supposed to show up on hover) is invisible until I click into the empty space.

Is there a way to upload screenshots to explain what I mean a bit better?

Comment: Do you have another css that works with your dropdown behavior? - To add images, edit your post and press Ctrl + G, or just click the Image button on the Editor! :)

Comment: thanks, I added the links to the screenshots in my original post :) 

the dropdown worked perfectly fine before I added the Slider to it... got the instructions for the dropdown from w3schools.com

Comment: Are you using some kind of jquery or javascript function that can cause it? Or, maybe, some css `:active` selector?

Comment: the only other Javascript is the `onClick="document.getElementById('socialMedia').style.display = 'block';"` to reveal the slider. I removed the `preview` class and now it looks better, but the slides are all lying on top of each other? (added a screenshot in the OP)